# HTML Agility Pack finding tag and inner text

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing, tags, html-agility-pack

Hey all i have the following html that i need to get text from:

```
<place.tag theBID="Example of text here and there" percentage="512.6">
     <... other html tags here ...>
    <longer.bid type="string">
        This is an example of the longer bid here and there.
    </longer.bid>
     <... other html tags here ...>
</place.tag>
```

And this is my VB.net code:

```
For Each listItem In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//place.tag[""longer.bid""]")
    Debug.Print(listItem.InnerText)
Next
```

The error i get on the **("//place.tag[""longer.bid""]")** part is:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am looking to get the text **This is an example of the longer bid here and there.** Problem is that i cant use **[@id=** or even **[@class=** to get the value since the **theBID** changes for each tag in the html.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why are you using the HTML Agility Pack to parse XML instead of an XML parser?

Comment: @Oded Because its wrapped within HTML so its not considered "XML" to a XML Parser since it does not start with the needed XML attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each listItem In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//place.tag//longer.bid")
    Debug.Print(listItem.InnerText)
Next
```